# Weblogic tries to access non-existing application while running an existing application

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I am trying to run an Oracle ADF application (eg. "MyApp") with JDeveloper IDE on Windows.

While I am running MyApp, Weblogic Server throws a DeploymentException that does not stop execution process of MyApp.

The error log is:

```
Failed to initialize the application 'Demo' due to error \
 weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [Deployer:149003]Unable to access \
  application source information in \
  'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.4.37.59.23\o.j2ee\drs\Demo' \
  for application 'Demo'. \
  The specific error is: [Deployer:149158] No application files exist at \ 
   'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.4.37.59.23\o.j2ee\drs\Demo'... \
   weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [Deployer:149003]Unable to access \
   application source information in \
  'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.4.37.59.23\o.j2ee\drs\Demo' \
  for application 'Demo'. \
The specific error is: [Deployer:149158] No application files exist at \
'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.4.37.59.23\o.j2ee\drs\Demo'..
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.verifyLocalApp(BasicDeployment.java:124)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.createDeployment(BasicDeployment.java:146)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:114)
                at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:39)
                at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:191)
```

Demo application is already been deleted from drs(Data Replication Service) folder and the application is closed in JDeveloper.

But it still tries to access Demo application files while compiling MyApp.I have searched this error but can not find any useful things.

I wonder why weblogic checks the drs folder for an application which does not exist in the drs folder.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the application from WLS directly from inside JDeveloper. see: https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/removing_applications_from_you

Answer (score 1):

Go into the WebLogic admin-console and ensure that all references to the demo application are removed from the list deployed of applications.

Comment: I tried to login to admin-console and remove the demo application this method also allows to undeploy the application.